# how Adding query string to url in jquery in django template

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

Im trying to add query string to url using jquery and when i do it using browser console by type

```
location.href =  '?grouping_by='+ 'daily' + '&start_date=123123123123';
```

it works fine and the browser take it.

but when im trying to add it in my html template it fails

here my code

```
<script>
$("#submit").click(function () {
            $("#target").click();
            var $grouping_by = $("#grouping_by");
            var $start_date = $("#start_date");
            var grouping_by = $grouping_by.val();
            var str_start_date = $start_date.val();
            var url =  '?grouping_by=' + grouping_by + '&start_date=' + str_start_date;

            location.href =  '?grouping_by='+ 'daily' + '&start_date=123123123123';


        });
</script>
```

I tried location.path and pathname but also nothing happens

any help ?

Comment: did you try to wrap your bind into document.onReady ?

Comment: when I did it redirected successfully, how can make it just when click?

Comment: I tried many ways to do that but I failed, I tried to call the function from on_click attr on input button. why when I make it document.onReady it works fine ?

Comment: because you tried to bind handler to element which was not in a DOM yet.